# Newgeometry in memoir, different results in different pages

Tags: memoir, fancyhdr, geometry, footer, header

I'm trying to create a document with the memoir class. The document needs to have a specific header and footer on the first page, and a different header and footer on the rest of the document.

I have tried with fancyheader but the second page is not getting it right (the text shifts up and invades the header, and the footer also shifts up).

Can anyone think of a way to do this with the headers and footers from the memoir class (without fancyheader)? The headers and footers are kind of complicated, with several lines.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime} % Para la fecha del informe
\usepackage{lastpage}  % Para saber cuantas paginas hay en el documento
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  % Para encabezados y pie de pagina
\usepackage{xcolor}    % Para texto de colores
\usepackage[lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,includefoot]{geometry}  % Para fijar los margenes

\begin{document}

\fancyhf{}  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  
\renewcommand{\today}{\the\day-\shortmonthname[\the\month]-\the\year}

\fancypagestyle{rest}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \lhead{\HUGE COMPANY NAME} 
    \rhead{     \footnotesize
        \begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip 0.5cm}r @{}}
            & AAA-TOPSECRET\\
            \ \\
            Code: & AAA-CDE-ITR-019\\
            Date: & \today\\
            Version: & 1\ \\
            Page: & \thepage\  of \pageref{LastPage}
        \end{tabular}
    }

    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \lfoot{\footnotesize DER}
    \rfoot{\footnotesize JHG Technical Report}
}

\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \lhead{\HUGE COMPANY NAME}
    \rhead{     AAA-TOPSECRET    }
    \lfoot{
        \begin{flushleft}
            \footnotesize 
            \begin{tabular}{@{} l@{\hskip 0.5cm}r }
                Prepared by: & John Smith\\
                Approved by: & Jake Smith\\
                Authorized by: & Jake Smith\\
            \end{tabular}
            \ \\[0.4cm]
            AAA Company\\
            www.testwebsite.com\\
            \textcolor{lightgray}{Custom} \textcolor{blue}{e}\textcolor{lightgray}{-Solutions.}
        \end{flushleft}
    }
    \rfoot{
        \begin{flushright}
            \footnotesize
                \begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip 0.5cm}r @{}}
                    Code: & AAA-CDE-ITR-019\\
                    Date: & \today\\Version: & 1\ \\
                    \ \\
                    \ & All rights reserved. \textcopyright \  AAA, 2019\\
                    \ \\
                    Internal code: & AAA 24466/19 V1/19
                \end{tabular}
        \end{flushright}}
    \cfoot{
        \ \\[3.5cm]\tiny \textcolor{gray}{The information contained within this document is considered as Secret. This information should/shall not be redistributed to non-allowed employees. The receiver is allowed to access this information precisely within conditions and for the explicit purposes previously or contractually agreed between the company and the receiver of the information; observing at all times legal regulations in intellectual property, personal data protection and other legal requirements where applicable.
        }
    }
}

\newgeometry{lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=6cm,includefoot}  

\pagestyle{rest}
\thispagestyle{titlepage}
\vspace*{\fill}
\HUGE{Test Technical Report}\\[0.3cm]
\LARGE{\textcolor{blue}{PROJECT (COMPANY)}}
\vspace*{\fill}

\newpage

\restoregeometry

Page 1 text
\newpage

Page 2 text
\newpage

Page 3 text
\newpage

Page 4 text

\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, I'm using lualatex, in case it makes any difference

Comment: Unlrelated you should never use `fancyhdr` with `memoir`. Memior has its own equivalent that is much better integrated into the class.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, I will check it out! Thank you!

Comment: I think you should describe your end goal a bit better. I'm not sure using newgeometry is the proper solution here, but I cannot figure out the details from what you have posted right now

Comment: Hi, if you compile the MWE, you will notice that in the second page the footer has been shifted up, as well as the text, which now is inside the header. I just want the second page to look like the third, fourth, etc, since they use the same style

Comment: That is not what I'm asking, I ask you to explicitly write down what the requirement is. It can most likely be made with that information alone, not needing your MWE (ref my mention of newgeometry probably being the wrong tool here)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The document needs to have a specific header and footer on the first page, and a different header and footer for the rest of the document. The problem I have right now is that page 2 (the first page of the second range) is not getting the geometry right. But that's it, one geometry and header and footer in the first page, and another geometry and header and footer on the rest. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please update the question with this information, what type of data should go on the first page, and on this others. What type of document is this? Is memoir even well suited for this (if for example this is a letter)

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I fixed it, the thread can be closed

Comment: For other visitors it might be an idea to list (as an update to your question) what you ended up doing

Comment: I haven't had a change to look at this until now (been at work). If that first page is just generated (like with `\makeitlte`) then I would not use headers and footers to place this information at all. I would probably design the entire title page separately and place the components on the page via absolute positioning. Then you can easily design the rest of the document with the normal design in mind and not have to deal with attempting to use to different layouts.